# Tools for SAT grounding?

Tags: declarative, satisfiability, answer-set-programming

In ASP (Answer Set Programming), programs are written in a higher-level declarative language and then grounded in a deterministic way to generate an ASP instance using a grounder like lparse or gringo.

Are there popular grounders the SAT community uses for generating instances?  In other words, is there something that could take an expression such as:

```
vertex(a; b; c).
isRed(V) \/ isBlue (V) \/ isGreen(V) :- vertex(V).
```

and generate a DIMACS file from it?

In general, how are SAT competition instances generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SAT competition](http://satcompetition.org/2014/cfp.shtml) benchmark instances are typically created by using specially tailored generator programs rather than general [ASP grounders](http://potassco.sourceforge.net/). The benchmark requirements are described [here](http://www.satcompetition.org/2009/format-benchmarks2009.html).

Other options to create a [CNF/DIMACS](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html) file include:

- Translate a Boolean expression via [Limboole](http://fmv.jku.at/limboole/), [bool2cnf](http://www-ise4.ist.osaka-u.ac.jp/~t-tutiya/sources/bool2cnf/) or
  [bc2cnf](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/#Tools)
- Compile a [MiniZinc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392219/convert-boolean-flatzinc-to-cnf-dimacs) constraint declaration into CNF/DIMACS
- Convert [ANF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_normal_form) to CNF with [anf2cnf](http://www.msoos.org/tag/anf/)

You might be interested to read the paper [There are no CNF problems](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/slides/SAT2013-stuckey.pdf). It motivates the usage of high-level languages like [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/).